# Do James 2:24 and Romans 3:28 contradict?

Tags: soteriology, textual-discrepancies, romans, book-of-james

(both quotes in NKJV)

James 2:24

> You see then that a man is justified by works, and not by faith only.

Romans 3:28

> For we maintain that a person is justified by faith apart from the
> works of the law.

It seems like James is saying we are justified by faith **and** works, but Paul is saying that we are justified by faith **alone**.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: No, if you believe in the Bible, Scriptures never contradict each other. If they do, then you have to accept the fact that God is a liar. However, the Bible disproves this.

Comment: This topic is already well covered here... one example among several is [this one](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/24935/how-are-the-teachings-in-the-book-of-james-consistent-with-salvation-by-grace-al), Also please check the Biblical HermeneuticsSE, which is where specific bible verses are better dealt with.  I'm afraid I have to vote to close, even though it is a very important question.

Comment: Actually you are missing a significant difference between the passages.  James speaks of **works**.  Paul speaks of **works of the law**

Comment: Paul is speaking of the law of works. We cannot be justified by the law of works, seeing as all have sinned. We can only be justified by the law of faith. But works (faith, repentance and so on) are still required.